# idiom for interface between view and controller

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, enums

I'm having a design question:

I am using the MVC design pattern. But the View is in my project the I/O-part. That means that part, which writes/reads data to/from the hard drive, or prints something on the screen.

Is I mentioned, the "view" should also perform read/write operations. Our program needs some input data to perform the wanted numerical calculation.
And as this input data should also be manually editable, we decided to make this input data as xml.

Then controller asks the "view" to read this xml input data so that the model can be filled.

This situation looks like this:

```
                                  Controller
                                   /     \
                                /           \
                             /                 \
                           View               Model
                          /    \
                       /          \
                    /                \
                xml reader         xml data
```

So the question now is, what to pass from the View to the Controller when it read the input data?

Should the view create instance of classes from the model and fill them with the input data and pass these instances to the Controller.

Or should it pass enums and floats to the Controller, so that he can instanciate the needed classes and give the floats to the constructors?

Which design is better, and why?

**Edit:** the reason why we thought, the view should contain the loading of the input data (now implemented as I/O to file) is, that in a future version of the code, we want to have a gui, where a user can point'n'click to build the input data. And then the view gets the exact same data (but then from a gui, and not from file) and should pass it to the controller. So now, it is just the simplest "view" (as the user interacts with the xml) possible. *Is that a right understanding of MVC?*

**Edit 2:** We implement a numerical method, like [FEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method). So the model contains two things: on the one hand it contains the data (which partially can be represented with xml), i.e. a representation of the finite elements and so on. And on the other hand it contains the logic, i.e. the partial differential equations, whose parameters should also be stored in the xml.
So the input data is needed for the logic in the model, not for the view.

If more information should be given, please feel free to ask.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure whether you understood model-view correctly. The model should hold (and most likely also read) any data necessary and the view should only be there to represent this data to the user.

Comment: @arne: I'm also not sure whether I understood it correctly :) So the question could be expanded to that part: "where does the I/O in MVC belong to?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Gang of Four, if I'm not mistaken, the Model class is the one who should perform the IO operations. 
The View is a presentation and allows the user or the controller to perform modifications to the Model, but should not be charged with IO operations as this violates encapsulation by exposing Model's internal representation.

If you need to have it done like this, I'd still suggest passing around entire Model objects, as this enables the controller not to be aware of the internal representation; if you pass around the internal data, all the view, controller and model need to be aware of Model's internals, which makes the three parts of the pattern even more coupled; while the intent in using it is to decouple the three parts as much as possible, allowing for bettere maintainability.

Comment: please see my edit of the original post. Keeping this (facts I wrote in the edit) in mind, would you still recommend putting the I/O into the Model?

Comment: Well Edit2 certainly reinforces my opinion; since the logic is complex, having the serialization done in the same class allows for an easier time in serializing/deserializing of the classes.

Edit1 can be resolved (if I understand it correctly!) by using a static factory on the model that can be leveraged by the controller through the data available in the view.

Having the IO in the view also means you're going to have to duplicate (or inherit) that when creating a different view; and modifying the internal model representation will force you to change the view, and the other way around.

Comment: Judging by comments on another answer, I might've missed your point.

I think the Model should have the methods to construct itself from data in a stream - xml and otherwise; the controller should ...control the external resources and pass streams for the model to use. Basically both view and model are very specific: view is presentation; model is internal logic; controller deals with the interaction between those two and the rest of the world.

Comment: Okay. I think I see your point. So you recommend that the controller calls the xml_reader to pass a stream (stringstream?) to the model, which constructs itself from that stream. Right?

Comment: Yep. And for the hypothetical future, I'd add a factory method to the model that constructs the correct object when passed necessary data. This way you can get stuff from the stream and leverage existing factory. In the future, you might have JSON, or the controller itself, or whathaveyou call the same factory.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you have two data models, in that case you should *consistently* follow the MVC pattern. The separation of components is there for a reason, this will especially help if you want to switch the xml for a gui later:

Model deals with the data, view allows you to take a look at it through it's own 'lens' and controller allows you to manipulate the model.

If your view needs some sort of input data you can implement a second MVC under that. You'll end up with a second model (model2: your xml data) plus a second controller. Right now your controller is the 'manual edit' of your second model. Later your controller will become part of the GUI, which will also have a second view onto your second model).

**Note**: see discussion in comments.

Comment: This is also what I thought of: implement the view as an on MVC. That's why I put the word `view` in quotation marks. But I think, I had other reasons than you... I don't exactly understand what you mean with "two data models"? My model contains of data (which partially can be represented with xml), and of the business logic which makes the calculations. The view itself doesn't need input data. It is the logic which needs it. Besides, you left the main question unanswered: when I make the view an own MVC, shall I pass enums or objects to my controller? Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Ok, I got your question wrong. You just have one MVC. If you follow the MVC pattern correctly, your view does NOT load any data (it only displays your model), the model represents the data. The model does the I/O (reads xml or text or from a database) and represents it in a way the view and controller can handle it. Take a look at this article from QT: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html . Maybe things will be more clear after that.

Comment: Okay, let's assume I would implement the model in such a way, that it loads the data from the xml file. How would I later on implement the way, that this data, which was formerly supplied via the xml file, is constructed via the gui? Then the gui, which is the view, has to pass this information to the model (probably via the controller, right?). So it seems to me, that I should implement the building of the model twice (once reading from xml and some other time constructing it via the view). And I learned the implementing something twice is really bad, isn't it?

Comment: No, if you follow the pattern, you'd implement the model once and the controller twice. One time your controller is the 'xml-reader' the other time it's the UI component. Think of the model as an internal data representation for your application. The controller is the manipulator of that data representation. I think the confusion stems from the fact that we very often merge those functionalities out of convenience (model+controller or view+controller are being implemented in one class).

Comment: Okay. So let's see if I got it: The controller calls the xml-reader to read the xml file, and then he get the values from the xml reader and fills the model. Right? All this is done by the controller? Seems a bit wrong to me...